# Can C# attributes access the e.g. PropertyInfo of the Property they are defined on?

Tags: c#, attributes, metaprogramming

I want to encode in attributes some computational definitions of the form "this field is a cached result of some computation on other fields of this class." The solution I have on hand is very incomplete because I can't... well...

Consider the following sketch:

```cs
// appropriate `using` declarations omitted for brevity
[AttributeUsage(Property)]
public class FooAttr : Attribute {
    private PropertyInfo _thing;
    public FooAttr() {
        _thing = GetMyProperty();
        System.Console.Out.WriteLn(_thing.Name); // or something else, w/e
    }
    private PropertyInfo GetMyProperty() {
        // magic
    }
}

public class Bar {
    [FooAttr]
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
// => writes "Baz" to stdout on loading this class
```

Is it possible to replace `// magic` with actual code, or is the solution to brute-force iterate over all possible classes and their properties until I find the specific one that matches this `FooAttr`?

I have scoured google for a straight answer to this question and found none.

Comment: What are you trying to solve with this? If i recall correctly the attributes constructor is only called if you explicitly retrieve the attribute like calling GetCustomAttributes on the proper PropertyInfo. But if you have the PropertInfo you already know where you are the Attribute does not need to find out of his own.

Comment: So the attribute class should be a factory pattern of some sort. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute objects are created upon request, and though it would be extremely convenient if there was a way for the attribute constructor to take as an argument the reflection object that produced it by way of `GetCustomAttributes` or the like, it is not currently possible.

Instead custom attributes needing this kind of functionality should use a factory pattern, where passing in the reflection object to some method performs the necessary computation, perhaps memoized in static fields in some fashion.